# Is it better to use a singleton for a web service

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, silverlight-5.0

In our application we use a singleton for a web service and that singleton is used for all classes.

I thought this was really cool, but then I saw a developers code where they had to unregister an event in the event handler itself.

This made me think back to just creating the wcf service and not having to worry about unregistering event handlers.  Also I thought that there might be a way that two classes could interfere with each other because they both listen to the same method's event handler.

What are the pros and cons of using a wcf singleton?  Does one way have better performance then the other?

Comment: Is the singleton used on the client or server side ?

Comment: Why singleton - is it because you are sharing some state across multiple clients?

Comment: It is on the client and only used by 1 client it is not shared across multiple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest reading this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx

Its a pretty good article which explains the different type of WCF services available, including singleton.

Comment: So it is, if I remember correctly almost exactly the same content can be found in Programming WCF Services by Juval Lowy, Chapter 4 Instance Management. A great book if you are working with WCF services and highly recommended.

Comment: Found Ch.4 on both the O'Reilly library and google books: https://library.oreilly.com/book/0636920032373/programming-wcf-services/88.xhtml, and https://books.google.com/books?id=PvNrurEhmiEC&pg=PA169&lpg=PA169&dq=Programming+WCF+Services+chapter+4